# How to fit font to cell height

Tags: fonts, fontsize, tabularray

So I am displaying font and I would like to make a split cell (or sub table) that fits the text in the second two cells vertically to match the height of the preceding text.

So like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\splitdetail}[3]{
    \hbox{
        \setbox1=\hbox{#1}\dimen1=\ht1 \box1 \the\dimen1\ \the\baselineskip \fontsize{.5\baselineskip}{.5\baselineskip}\selectfont\the\baselineskip
        \vbox to\dimen1{
            \halign{
                \hfil##\hfil\cr #2 \the\baselineskip \cr\noalign{\vss} #3 \cr
            }
        }
    }
}
\Huge\splitdetail{\faMapMarker}{City}{State}
\end{document}
```

But the text runs over because of the letters that dip below the line (but my understand is that shouldn't be happening, because this space is included in `\baselineskip`, no?[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. But the first symbol is just under 20pts tall, and by selecting the font for the `City` and `State` to be 15pts tall, you are guaranteed to have overlaps (if you insert negative glue to force the whole thing as tall as the map symbol). Can you show a mock up of what you want the output to actually look like?

Comment: Also: not all combinations of letters realize a height (top of the tallest to the bottom of the deepest) equal to the point size specified. If you don't want any overlaps, maybe you can replace using `\fontsize{.5\dimen1}{.5\dimen1}`, but this will generically result in some amount of white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you, I first measure the height of the large text. However, the `\faMapMarker` sticks below the baseline, so I add the depth of the text to it. And I shift this text up with the depth so that it will just stand on the baseline. Otherwise the `\faMapMarker` will be lower than the text next to it.

I then typeset the small text with a fixed font size (I have chosen 25pt but it could be any other that LaTeX knows). Then I measure the height of the box with the two lines. I then multiply the font size by the ratio of the desired height and the measured height and use that to finally typeset the small text. I have used standard LaTeX commands to do the measuring, rather than `\box1` and `\dimen1`. I find that cleaner.

Please note that LaTeX may round the fontsize to one of the sizes that it knows. To compensate for that I add a `\vss` between the two lines. It is also possible to put `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` before the `\documentclass`, then LaTeX will not round the font size. I have commented this out in my code below. Still the `\vss` is helpful, as the font sizes are not necessarily scaled exactly.

You can choose left aligned, centered or right aligned by putting `\hfil` at the proper places.

```
%\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\DimA % height of large text
\newlength\DimB % height of smaller text
\newlength\smallsize % fontsize of smaller text
\newsavebox\tempbox

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\splitdetail}[3]{
    \hbox{%
        \sbox{\tempbox}{#1}
        \setlength{\DimA}{\dimexpr\ht\tempbox+\dp\tempbox}%
        \raisebox{\dp\tempbox}{\usebox{\tempbox}}
        \setlength{\smallsize}{25pt}% initial try
        \settoheight{\DimB}{\vbox{%
            \fontsize\smallsize\smallsize\selectfont
            \halign{##\cr#2\cr#3\cr}}}%
        \setlength\smallsize{\smallsize*\ratio{\DimA}{\DimB}}%
        \fontsize{\smallsize}{\smallsize}\selectfont
        \vbox to\DimA{\halign{##\cr#2\hfil\cr\noalign{\vss}#3\hfil\cr}}%
    }
}

\Huge
\splitdetail{LARGE TEXT}{Small Top}{Small Bottom}

\splitdetail{\faMapMarker}{City}{State}

\end{document}
```

[image]